# How to use FileSystem.getInfoAsync() with Expo?

Tags: react-native, filesystems, expo

I'm trying to test if a file exists with expo.

This is the expo doc :
*Returns
If no item exists at this URI, returns { exists: false, isDirectory: false }. Else returns an object*

```
if (this._liste.length === 0) {
               let tmp =FileSystem.getInfoAsync('file://exemple.json');

                if(tmp.exists === false){
                    alert("not found")
                }
            }
```

The File doesn't exist, I'm sure and the alert doesn't show.
When I print tmp, I have a **Object** but when I print tmp.exist I have a **undefined**.

Answer (score 5):

getInfoAsync is an async function therefore you cannot use it like a normal function. It returns a Promise so you either need to use await or then:

### await

```
let tmp = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync('file://exemple.json');
// use tmp.exists
```

### then

```
FileSystem.getInfoAsync('file://exemple.json').then(tmp => {
// use tmp.exists
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getInfoAsync()` returns this (example):

```
Object {
 "exists": 1,
 "isDirectory": true, // notice isDirectory == true
 "modificationTime": 1532926143,
 "size": 102,
 "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9D3661AF-8EB5-49F5-A178-3ECA0F96BEEC/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FWAMS-1163fc3b-4484-44a2-9076-b4b71df1e55c/avatar/",
}
```

If you want to read what files are in a directory, use
[FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreaddirectoryasyncfileuri)

Comment: I know but I want to test if the file exist but I can't access to the field "exists" it return an undefined

Comment: did you try `console.log(tmp.exists) or console.log(tmp)`?

Comment: Yes and tmp.exists print Undefined and console.log(tmp) Object but I don't think the object is the same that you give me.

Comment: can you try  `t = JSON.parse(tmp);`   and `console.log(t.exists);`